# Question about approximation of the solution of heat equation on the half-line

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

We have the heat equation:
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}$ on the positive half-line $x>0$.

with the boundary condition $u(t,0)=0$.

The initial condition is compactly supported.

I want to show that the solution has the following approximation: $u(t,x) \approx \frac{x}{t^\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}} $

I am not sure how to go about proving this, any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Asymptotics for large $t$?. I assume this equation is already in dimensionless form because if not, it does not make much sense.

Comment: Can you explain your edits? What made you change the heat equation to a different form? What makes you think the approximation will be of that form?

Comment: Hi, I had to edit the question because it turns out this is what I actually need to show.